# WP Editor, save content and category on frontend

Tags: plugins, posts, wp-editor

I'm creating a plugin that shows a frontend editor that will be the content of the current post. But I don't know who to save the content from the wp_editor to the post content;

I tried using on form action admin_url('post.php'), but I didn't work. I have been checking around but I didn't find any solution.

Thanks!

Here's what I have now:

```
function front_end_editor(){
    //if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $settings = array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'tinymce' => true,
            'textarea_name' => 'fe_content'
        );
        if(is_single() || is_page()){
            //admin_url('post.php')
            echo '<form action="' . get_permalink() . '" method="get">';
            wp_editor(esc_html(get_the_content()), 'textarea_post', $settings);
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="save" value="true"/>';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>';

            if($_REQUEST['save'] == true){
                global $post;
                $post->post_content = '$_REQUEST['fe_content'];
            }
        }
    //}
}

add_action('the_content', 'front_end_editor');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use WordPress's Ajax API. like this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        action: 'save_post_frontend',
        content: // get your text
    },
    method: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    success: // on success
});
```

Now save the data in wp_ajax_save_post_frontend hook.
See documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks but works with wp_insert_post()